# Inject services to controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a class of Controller with constructor() and method.

```
static $inject = ['$stateParams', '$location', 'defectResource', 'entityProvider'];

constructor($stateParams: any, $location: any, defectResource: any, entityProvider: any) {
    if (typeof $stateParams.defectid != 'undefined') {
        this.defectid = $stateParams.defectid;


        defectResource.defectByDefectId(this.defectid).then((data) => {
                this.defect = data;
        });

     } else {

        // create new Defect
        this.defect = entityProvider.newDefect($stateParams.itemid);
     }
}

postDefect($stateParams: any, $location: any, defectResource: any): void {
    defectResource.postDefect(this.defect).then(function () {
        $location.path('defects/' + $stateParams.itemid);
    });
};
```

This code is working, but I am not using `$location` in the constructor. It is used only the `postDefect()` mtehod.  But I cannot remove it from constructor parameters, because constructor parameters list must be the same as `$inject` list.

Is there any way not to pass `$location` to constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I cannot remove it from constructor parameters, because constructor parameters list must be the same as $inject list. Is there any way not to pass $location to constructor?

If the class needs it (since a function needs it) ... best to have it up front as a dependency in the constructor which is what you have.

Just a minor thing ... store it in the class using `public` e.g.:

```
constructor($stateParams: any, public $location: any, defectResource: any, entityProvider: any)
```

> Is there any way not to pass $location to constructor?

In the constructor get `$injector` instead of `$location` and then call `$injector.get('$location')` when you actually need it. Warning: this will make your code harder to review for the next guy `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand correctly that you recomment me leave my code as it  is?

Comment: @demas yes. That would be ideal

Answer (score 2):

You could skip it in postDefect() and then use this.$location instead.

And you shouldn't use 'any'  all over the place, get the DefinitelyTyped files you need from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
And include them in your project.

Comment: To do it, i need to assign contructor parameter to class varibable in constructor, right? Something like `this.$location = $location`.

Comment: Yes, I see. I was needed to declare it as public. Thanks.